# Converting security function from v2 to v4

Tags: pine-script

```
yesterday=security(tickerid, '60', ohlc4[1])
today=security(tickerid, '60', ohlc4)
delta=today-yesterday
percentage=delta/yesterday
```

this was done in  pine version 2
i have tried changing this to

```
yesterday=security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ohlc4[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
today=security(tickerid, '60', ohlc4)
delta=today-yesterday
percentage=delta/yesterday
```

but this gives totally different results  , can somebody please help

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the `lookahead` parameter was `barmerge.lookahead_on` for versions prior to v3.

So, you should add this in your second `security()` call too.

```
yesterday=security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', ohlc4[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
today=security(tickerid, '60', ohlc4, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
delta=today-yesterday
percentage=delta/yesterday
```